# Issue feeding a list into feed_dict in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to pass a list into `feed_dict`, however I'm having trouble doing so. Say I have:

```
inputs = 10 * [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, input_size))]
```

where inputs is fed into some function `outputs` that I want to compute. So to run this in tensorflow, I created a session and ran the following:

```
sess.run(outputs, feed_dict = {inputs: data}) 
#data is my list of inputs, which is also of length 10
```

but I get an error, `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.`
However, I'm able to pass the data element-wise like so:

```
sess.run(outputs, feed_dict = {inputs[0]: data[0], ..., inputs[9]: data[9]})
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way I can solve this issue. I've also tried to construct a dictionary(using a `for` loop), however this results in a dictionary with a single element, where they key is: 
`tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor at 0x107594a10`

Comment: Have you tried sess.run(outputs, feed_dict=dict(zip(inputs, data))) ?

Comment: Yea, I get the same issue as with the for loop method.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are two issues that are causing problems here:

The first issue is that the [`Session.run()`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client.md#Session.run) call only accepts a small number of types as the keys of the `feed_dict`. In particular, lists of tensors are ***not*** supported as keys, so you have to put each tensor as a separate key.<sup>*</sup> One convenient way to do this is using a dictionary comprehension:

```
inputs = [tf.placeholder(...), ...]
data = [np.array(...), ...]
sess.run(y, feed_dict={i: d for i, d in zip(inputs, data)})
```

The second issue is that the `10 * [tf.placeholder(...)]` syntax in Python creates a list with ten elements, where each element is ***the same tensor object*** (i.e. has the same `name` property, the same `id` property, and is reference-identical if you compare two elements from the list using `inputs[i] is inputs[j]`). This explains why, when you tried to create a dictionary using the list elements as keys, you ended up with a dictionary with a single element - because all of the list elements were identical.

To create 10 different placeholder tensors, as you intended, you should instead do the following:

```
inputs = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, input_size))
          for _ in xrange(10)]
```

If you print the elements of this list, you'll see that each element is a tensor with a different name.

---

**EDIT:** <sup>*</sup> You can now pass **tuples** as the keys of a `feed_dict`, because these may be used as dictionary keys.

Comment: *lists of tensors are not supported as keys, so you have to put each tensor as a separate key* @mrry, is this still true? In my case, I'm passing a tuple of LSTMStateTuple objects as a key to `sess.run()`, in TensorFlow r0.11

Comment: Tuples work as keys now, but lists still raise an error because Python lists aren't usable as dictionary keys. I updated the answer to  clarify.

Comment: What if I feed multiple iterations? ex) feed_dict={x:y for x,y in (nodes,inputs), node_another: input_another} #this doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

Here is a correct example:

```
batch_size, input_size, n = 2, 3, 2
# in your case n = 10
x = tf.placeholder(tf.types.float32, shape=(n, batch_size, input_size))
y = tf.add(x, x)

data = np.random.rand(n, batch_size, input_size)

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: data})
```

And here is a strange things I see in your approach. For some reason you use `10 * [tf.placeholder(...)]`, which creates 10 tensors of size `(batch_size, input_size)`. No idea why do you do this, if you can just create on Tensor of rank 3 (where the first dimension is 10).

Because you have a list of tensors (and not a tensor), you can not feed your data to this list (but in my case I can feed to my tensor).

Comment: So the reason I did that was because I'm trying to use the rnn method provided in tensorflow, and when I pass a 3 dimensional tensor I get an error: "TypeError: inputs must be a list".

Comment: So I was also able to solve the issue by passing a 3-d tensor and then splitting and squeezing it, and passing the input into my operation/function that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

feed_dict can be provided by preparing a dictionary beforehand as follows

```
n = 10
input_1 = [tf.placeholder(...) for _ in range(n)]
input_2 = tf.placeholder(...)
data_1 = [np.array(...) for _ in range(n)]
data_2 = np.array(...)


feed_dictionary = {}
for i in range(n):
    feed_dictionary[input_1[i]] = data_1[i]
feed_dictionary[input_2] = data_2
sess.run(y, feed_dict=feed_dictionary)
```