# How to feed sequence of images to a tf.placeholder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, video, tensorflow, sequence, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to make an RNN that can classify sequences of images. I load my data into an ndarray which has the shape

```
data = (n_sequences, n_frames, image_width, image_height, channels)
```

and I have 2 classes, `1` and `0`.

I create a placeholder to feed the data to during training and I reshape it somewhat:

```
n_input = image_width*image_height*channels

train_data_node = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32,
    shape=(batch_size, n_frames, n_input)
)

# Permuting batch_size and n_frames
train_data_node = tf.transpose(train_data_node, [1, 0, 2])

# Reshaping to (n_frames*batch_size, n_input)
train_data_node = tf.reshape(train_data_node, [-1, n_input])

# Split to get a list of 'n_frames' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
train_data_node = tf.split(0, n_frames, train_data_node)
```

For now I set `batch_size = 1` and for each training step I get the next sample as:

```
batch_x = train_data[step,...]
batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, n_frames, n_input))
```

And then I run

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={train_data_node: batch_x})
```

And I get the following error:

```
line 337, in main
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={train_data_node: batch_x,
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I tried fixing this by casting `batch_x` into a `tuple` which is an immutable datatype, but I still get the same error even though everything is a `tuple` when I debug:

```
batch_x={tuple}<type 'tuple'>: (((255.0, 218.0, 234.0, ..., 65.0, 131.0)),)
```

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684657/issue-feeding-a-list-into-feed-dict-in-tensorflow) and tried it, which gave me other issues regarding dimensions. When I fix the dimension issues it throws the exact same errors as before. I think I am doing something wrong, but I have no idea what :\

Comment: The output of `tf.split` is a list. You cannot use a list as the key of `feed_dict`. Maybe you can try `input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(...); train_data_node = tf.transpose(input_placeholder, [1, 0, 2]); ...`, and `sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={input_placeholder: batch_x})`

Comment: So I got it to work now, thanks to your comment. Basically I just left out the `tf.reshape` and `tf.split` and just defined the placeholder as `train_data_node = tf.transpose(train_data_node, [1, 0, 2])`.