# Tensorflow cannot feed the value of shape(1,) for Tensor 'x:0' which has the shape '(?, 128)'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, shapes

I just browsed through Stack Overflow and other forums but couldn't find anything helpful for my problem. But it seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684657/issue-feeding-a-list-into-feed-dict-in-tensorflow).

I currently have a trained model of Tensorflow (128 inputs and 11 outputs) which I saved, following the MNIST tutorial by Tensorflow.

It seemed to be successful and I have a model in this folder now with the 3 files (.meta, .ckpt.data and .index). However, I want to restore it and use it for predictions:

```
#encoding[0] => numpy ndarray (128, ) # anyway a list with only one entry
#unknowndata = np.array(encoding[0])[None]
unknowndata = np.expand_dims(encoding[0], axis=0)
print(unknowndata.shape) # Output (1, 128)

# Restore pre-trained tf model
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #saver.restore(sess, "models/model_1.ckpt")
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('models/model_1.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('models/./'))
    y = tf.get_collection('final tensor') # tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y2, W3) + b3)
    X = tf.get_collection('input') # tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128])

    # W1 = tf.get_collection('vars')[0]
    # b1 = tf.get_collection('vars')[1]
    # W2 = tf.get_collection('vars')[2]
    # b2 = tf.get_collection('vars')[3]
    # W3 = tf.get_collection('vars')[4]
    # b3 = tf.get_collection('vars')[5]

    # y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W1) + b1)
    # y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)
    # yLog = tf.matmul(y2, W3) + b3
    # y = tf.nn.softmax(yLog)

    prediction = tf.argmax(y, 1)

    print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={i: d for i,d in zip(X, unknowndata.T)}))
    # also had sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: unknowndata.T}) and also not transposed, still errors

# Output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] # one should be 1 obviously with a specific percentage
```

There I only run in problems ...

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1,) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 128)'
>   Altough I print the shape of the 'unknowndata' and it matches the (1, 128).
>   I also tried it with

```
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: unknownData})) # with transposed etc. but nothing worked for me there I got the other error
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I only want some predictions of this beautiful Tensorflow trained model.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! People here are busy helping out as much as they can so not everyone will have the time to read through a wall of code. I recommend you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46496213/edit) your post to include a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. It will help you getting replies that will help.

Comment: how about `sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X[0]: unknownData}))`?

Comment: that's what I tried and it worked but there it only takes 1 sample of the 128 data and not all of them right? The output would also just give me eleven times zero (there is no one altough at least one should be there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prediction` tensor is obtained by an argmax on `y`. Instead of returning only `prediction`, you can add `y` to your output feed when you execute `sess.run`.

```
output_feed = [prediction, y]
preds, probs = sess.run(output_feed, print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={i: d for i,d in zip(X, unknowndata.T)}))
```

`preds` will have the predictions of the model and`probs` will have the probability scores.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem!
First I need to restore all of the values (weights and biases and matmul them seperately).
Second I need to create the same input as in the trained model, in my case:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128])
```

and then just call the prediction:

```
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: unknownData})
```

But I do not get any percentage distribution but I expect that due to the softmax function. Does anybody know how to access those?

Answer (score 0):

First when you save, you have to add to the collection the placeholders you need  tf.add_to_collection('i', i) and then retrieve them and pass them the feed_dict.

In your example is "i":

```
i = tf.get_collection('i')[0]
#sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={i: d for i,d in zip(X, unknowndata.T)})
```