# How to feed list of values to a placeholder list in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to feed list of values into a placeholder list. I have created the placeholder list as:

```
self.sample_set = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,self.max_input_right])
      for _ in xrange(10)]
```

I am trying to feed in the following way:

```
feed_dict= {cnn.sample_set:d1 for d1 in data[10],                            
            cnn.question: data[0],
            cnn.answer: data[1],
            cnn.answer_negative:data[2]}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as it gives syntax error.
I was following the below example:
[Issue feeding a list into feed_dict in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684657/issue-feeding-a-list-into-feed-dict-in-tensorflow)

I am looking to maintain list of values with rank 2 tensor instead of maintaining a 3 rank tensor because I want to process each of these values separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of instantiating `feed_dict` is:

```
feed_dict = { tf.placeholder object : python value }
```

In your case, one of the keys of `feed_dict` (`cnn.sample_set`) is a list of `tf.placeholder`s, which does not correspond to the above-mentioned syntax.

A solution would be:

```
feed_dict = {
               placeholder : value 
                  for placeholder, value in zip(cnn.sample_set, data[10])
            }

feed_dict.update(
            {
               cnn.question : data[0],
               cnn.answer : data[1],
               cnn.answer_negative : data[2]
            }
           )
```