# How can i feed a list into feed_dict in tensorflow? The elements of list have different shapes

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

I want to pass a list into feed_dict, however I'm having trouble doing so. In my code:

```
temp1=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10])
temp2=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10,30])
temp3=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5,15,8])
list1.append(temp1)
list1.append(temp2)
list1.append(temp3)
```

where list1 is fed into a function.
According to the web:[Issue feeding a list into feed_dict in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684657/issue-feeding-a-list-into-feed-dict-in-tensorflow)

I write the code:

```
data = [np.array(...), ...] ####data is the input of list1
sess.run(y, feed_dict={i: d for i, d in zip(list1, data)})
```

but I get an error:invalid syntax

How can i solve this problem?

I have studied the web:[Issue feeding a list into feed_dict in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684657/issue-feeding-a-list-into-feed-dict-in-tensorflow,but) it can not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use python functions with tensor objects (list1).  The for loop likely does not know how to handle placeholders.
Maybe try:

dictionary = dict(zip(list1, data))